# How can I see the content of a ResultSet object inspecting it using the Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide, resultset

I have the following problem using the Eclipse debugger.

I have to inspect a **ResultSet rs** object containing some rows obtained from a query.

I put my **rs** object into the Eclipse debugger **expression** area to analize it content but I can't understand how do the following things:

1. Where are stored the number of rows contained into my ResultSet object.
2. How can I see the rows inside the **expression** area of the debugger? (I want see the rows and its content)

Comment: The ResultSet only contains the current row and does not know the total number of rows.

Answer (score 4):

You can't:

https://www.java67.com/2018/01/jdbc-how-to-get-row-and-column-count-from-resultset-java.html

Because Java Database Connectivity uses a streaming API, it doesn't return all of the results at once.